# Xamarin.iOS Write NFC

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How can I use Xamarin.iOS to write an NFC tag? Assuming this is not yet possible - since I can't find anything mentioning this in the API documentation or in the release notes of Xamarin Forms: is there a timeline when this can be expected?

Also, is there currently a way around it?

Comment: It is already supported in Xamarin.iOS via the iOS 13 support that was added back at the end of September, it is using the additions made to CoreNFC: Apple has a Swift-based examples that convert to Xamarin.iOS fairly quickly (the FishTagCreater app, just a few dozen lines of code) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/creating_nfc_tags_from_your_iphone?language=objc

Comment: Thanks for that link. I did not find any Xamarin.iOS API that I can use to translate that example to. All I could find on learn.microsoft.com about corenfc was related to iOS11 (i.e. reading ndef record payload only): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios11/corenfc and nearby pages. How can I write an APDU command?

Comment: Do not have my code in front of me, but you get a tag back from your NFCTagReaderSession and each type of tag has a SendCommand (ObjC: sendCommandAPDU) method on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of Xamarin.iOS is that everything you can do with the native Apple libraries, you can do in C#. So if something is possible using Swift using the native libraries, you will be able to do it using the C# version of that library, using CoreNFC in your case.

So your next step is just figuring out how to write that Swift/Obj-C code in C#.
Using the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/creating_nfc_tags_from_your_iphone?language=objc), it's clear that you have only certain types of tags you can write to using an iPhone. So let's choose to go with the NFCISO7816Tag.

First you would have to create a class that implements `INFCIso7816Tag`. So I created `NFCIso7816Tag` that implements `INFCIso7816Tag`. I fill out everything appropriately. And after that, inside my code I create an instance of `NFCIso7816Tag` and also create an `actionHandler` delegate of type `NFCIso7816SendCompletionHandler`. So your code would look something like this:

```
var tag = new NFCMiFareTag();
tag.SendCommand(new NFCIso7816Apdu(...), actionHandler);
```

Lastly, don't forget to use the newer devices, since you can't write to NFCs on the older devices!

[Here's a list of projects](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=using%20CoreNFC%3B&type=Code) that use CoreNFC, it might give you a headstart on how to implement it yourself!

---

Edit May 2020:

I wrote an article that explains [How to get started with NFC on iOS and Android apps using Xamarin Forms](https://medium.com/@prototypemakers/start-building-with-nfc-rfid-tags-on-ios-android-using-xamarin-today-2268cf86d3b4?sk=f0cb84c6ae3fdf500f9a2926821b7a84) and also created [this video](https://youtu.be/STfzU18v7gE). There’s an awesome nuget package for Xamarin forms called Plugin.NFC that also allows you to write Tags using iOS too

Comment: @parvus where you able to figure this out? I just updated my answer with new information